Could not resolve compiling @angular/animations
I need help, i want to  resolve  this  problème,  but i can't because, i dont know where start
enter image description here
when  i  run my lacal server  with ng serve, i get this error
this is after  insttalling
npm install ngx-toastr --save

here my  dependencies :
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@ngneat/hot-toast": "^7.0.0",
    "@ngneat/overview": "^6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },


In the npm website I can see the below instructions please try them.
npm install ngx-toastr --save

@angular/animations package is a required dependency for the default toast
npm install @angular/animations --save

Don't want to use @angular/animations? See Setup Without Animations.

Hi @Naren,  when  i use without Animation,    ToastNoAnimationModule.forRoot()
I get  this  error Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
An unhandled exception occurred: Missing "./toastr/toastr.module" specifier in "ngx-toastr" package
See "C:\Users\mycompytar\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-WnAWSX\angular-errors.log" for further details.

in  log file we find  this details [error] Error: Missing "./toastr/toastr.module" specifier in "ngx-toastr" package
